# How get minutes from timestamp without zero?

Tags: php

Now I have a second when user was online: 670. How I can show how much minutes user was online at minutes without zero?

I tried: `echo date('i', 670);`

Comment: What you mean with: `without zero at first`?

Comment: And your problem is? `$minutes = ltrim(date('i', $timestamp),'0');`

Comment: There is a manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I mean that if use function `date('i')` it returns me format 01, 02 minutes. But I need only 1, 2, ...59

Comment: That's not really something you should use `date()` for. Try `floor( 670 / 60 )`

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need to use `date()` for this. Assuming your variable for seconds is stored in `$seconds`, you can do this:

```
$minutes = $seconds / 60;
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/231590)

You can then use either [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php), [`floor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) or [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) depending upon your needs.

If you need both the minutes, and seconds, you can use the following:

```
$minutes = $seconds / 60;
$secs    = $seconds % 60;
```

[**Demo 2**](https://eval.in/231597)